Next JS 14: In build mode, fetch requests do not work because the latest relevant data that is in the DB is not visible
In development mode, everything is fine. All fetch requests are made and the current data from the DB is visible. But when I build the application (deploy), new data that is written to the DB is not visible or is not updated, or maybe even requests are not made when entering the site, it is not clear.
Please review the code that receives news from /api (it is also correctly configured along the path /api/news/route.js). And by the way, I did everything on SSR so that there would be no problems with SEO:

    export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
    
    import Header from "@/components/Main/Header/Header";
    import TournamentBlock from "@/components/Main/TournamentBlock/TournamentBlock";
    import config from '../../public/conf.json';
    import VKPosts from "@/components/Main/VKPosts/VKPosts";
    import NewsFeed from "@/components/Main/NewsFeed/NewsFeed";
    import Broadcasts from "@/components/Main/Broadcasts/Broadcasts";
    import TVSchedule from "@/components/Main/TVSchedule/TVSchedule";
    import Tags from "@/components/Main/Tags/Tags";
    import TransferList from "@/components/Main/TransferList/TransferList";
    
    async function fetchNews() {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`http://78.46.254.73:3000/api/news`, {cache: 'no-store'});
        return await res.json();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return [];
      }
    }
    
    const Page = async () => {
      const news = await fetchNews();
    
      return (
        <>
          <Header news={news} />
          <TournamentBlock news={news} leagueId={config.mainPageLeagueIds[0]} />
          <div className="newsFeeds">
            <NewsFeed news={news} />
            <VKPosts />
          </div>
          <TournamentBlock news={news} leagueId={config.mainPageLeagueIds[1]} />
          <div className="broadcasts-tv-schedule">
            <Broadcasts />
            <TVSchedule />
          </div>
          <div className="tags-transfers">
            <Tags news={news} />
            <TransferList />
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Page;


I also tried to do getServerSideProps, but when I call "props" inside the component, it displays "undefined". I also used { cache: 'no-cache' } so that the data is cached if it is new.
Please help me with this problem. In case of incorrectly written code and the problem itself - criticism is welcome.

It's working with { cache: 'no-store' }. For { cache: 'no-cache' } to work, the server must provide the proper meta data: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/03/referrer-and-cache-control-apis-for-fetch. You should probably configure the server accordingly.
Make sure you have the following folder structure:
└───app
    ├───layout.tsx
    └───page.tsx

with layout.tsx being:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}

and page.tsx being:
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'; // required b/c `fetch` is invoked dynamically and so page cannot be rendered statically anymore

async function fetchNews() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`http://78.46.254.73:3000/api/news`, { cache: 'no-store' }});
        return await res.json();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

export default async function Page() {
    const data = await fetchNews()
    return <main>{JSON.stringify(data.reverse())}</main>
}

Run next build && next start (to create a production build and run it), visit http://localhost:3000 and see there's a result.
Some notes:

getServerSideProps is for the outdated pages approach (Next.js < 13) and won't work with the app directory.
SEO isn't related to your problem.
SSR doesn't really matter here. What's important is that it's a React Server Component (not to be confused with Next.js server side rendering, which applies to both React Server Components and React Client Components!), and therefore async is allowed.


Actually i use command: npm run build then npm run start. Because when i write next build, console write me: Command 'next' not found, but can be installed with:...
I guess there are no difference between "npm" and "next"

What about my folder structure:
└───app
├───layout.js
└───page.js
And inside page.js i using fetch:
async function fetchNews() {
try {
const res = await fetch(http://78.46.254.73:3000/api/news, { cache: 'no-cache' });
return await res.json();
}
catch (err) {
console.error(err);
}
}
const page = async () => {
const news = await fetchNews();
...
}
But after building project with "npm run build" then "npm run start", fetch does not request, despite the fact that JSON has already been updated.

@MuradImanov npm run build runs the command you can find in you package.json under scripts with the same name (i.e. build), and the same for npm run start.
Your folder structure looks like mine, apart from that you don't use TypeScript but JavaScript (hence j instead of t in the suffix) and no React Component syntax yet (hence no x in the suffix).
Regarding your error, I thought it wouldn't query at all. If it just won't update, use the setting { cache: 'no-store' }. I'll add it to my answer.

Update: I checked, actually, you are using React Component syntax. So I'ld recommend to rename the files from .js to .jsx.

All of my components extensions is "jsx", except of page.js, bacause it is default by next js.
What about "no-store", i change "no-cache" to "no-store", but during the project build, the console gives an error:
https://imgur.com/vwk2XGD
https://imgur.com/bJo4Tgi
https://imgur.com/M0rxR9K
Please see how to solve the problem, I really need your help.

Ah, yes. You've gotta forbid now that page.js gets build statically. Add export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'; to the file. Also, you should rename the page.js to page.jsx b/c stuff like <Header /> is not plain Java Script anymore, but JavaScript extended with React syntax.

@MuradImanov Did that help or is there still something unclear? If it's working now, please accept the answer, otherwise feel free to ask for clarifications.

Please don't close the topic. I'm testing the code with "force dynamic" for now. I'll let you know for sure.

Unfortunately this method also didnt working (force-engine and cache: no-store). İ rewrited my code to the final version, which did not work.

is there any way to discuss this issue and have you interact directly with the project?

@MuradImanov What didn't work? I've checked again, the only thing which now is causing trouble is that the url form above doesn't return data anymore. Probably the ip has changed. Here's a  link to a working, minimal example: https://github.com/JonasDoe/fetch-dynamic. That said, you've gotta replace http://78.46.254.73:3000/api/news with a working url.

Yes, beacuse of i turned off the server for a while. Now, its turned on. But it  is not reason...

In dev mode data is updated with new JSON, but not with build mode

@MuradImanov I've pushed another version with github, where the data is fetched from a dummy server which returns the current date. The seconds returned from this server change whenever I hit refresh. Please have a look at the repository, and follow the instructions to test it yourself. If it isn't working with your url, then something is missing there - the Next.js side is just working fine.

After so much time I figured it out, I think XD. It turns out that my problem is not in the client (I assume), but on the server. As I see, it turns out that the JSON itself does not change on the server, that is, it turns out that route.js does not access the DB when entering the site? Here is my code /api/news/route.js:

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import db from '@/libs/db';
export async function GET() {
let connection;
try {
connection = await db.getConnection();
const [data] = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10');
connection.release();
return NextResponse.json(data);
}
catch(err) {
console.error(err);
if (connection) connection.release();
return NextResponse.error(err);
}
}

@MuradImanov Well, if your server endpoint is implemented in Next.js, then you might have to force-dynamic there, too.

Yes! force-dynamic worked. I wrote only in file "route.js". Will this be optimized for my application? Regardless of whether to add it to routesjs or to the client component.

@MuradImanov force-dynamic basically disables big parts of the optimization of this particular file. But the optimization wouldn't have made much sense here anyway (as you experiences with that bug). That said, if the endpoint does a DB query everytime you invoke it, the performance impact of this query will be much bigger than the missing optimization of the route.js. If you want to improve the performance, that would be the place to investigate - but it will be much more complicated, depends on your infrastructue and the way you use it. It's out of scope for this particular question. ;)

Thank you for helping! At least "force-dynamic" in route.js solved my problem.
